# Careers: specify contract type by location

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I'd like to be able to say "looking for full-time employment at my current location, but would also be interested in short-term contracts abroad in countries X, Y and Z"; but the interface does not currently permit me to be this specific, leaving me with a choice of either potentially missing out or potentially wasting recruiter time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is somewhat unusual, couldn't you indicate this in your personal statement?

It seems a bit onerous to make everyone fill out specific goals for each location they wish to work.

The primary goal is to match by location -- so I think I'd rather have slightly too-broad matching in this case and err on the side of too many results and having the hiring manager screen based on your personal statement, rather than increasing complexity for everyone across the board.

Comment: Hi Jeff, this is not that unusual. Contractors in the EU are mobile to the extent that we travel anywhere in the EU for work. It's annoying that I can't enter the "European Union" the same way that I could enter the "United States". From an employment point of view they are both a confederation of states, where if you are a citizen of one of the member states you have a legal right to work in other member states. Does that make sense?